# css li pading itself

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this div element

```
<div class="foodsSection">
    <label>
        Foods:
    </label>
    <ul>
        <li>
            here
        </li>  
    </ul>
</div>
```

the results is :
[image]

but when i add `li` elements from jquery, the results become this:
[image]

why the padding to the left and how to solve it please?

#### jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("..RestauranstSection li").click(function (){
        var divYourOrder = $(".YourOrder");
        var li = $(".OMRestaurants li");
        var restaurantID = 8;
        var foodDive = $(".foodsSection ul");
        foodDive.html("");
        var lis = '<ul>';
        $.getJSON("http://localhost/TheEatTel/Food/getFoodForRestaurant/"+restaurantID+"/TRUE",function(data){
            for(var i=0;i<data.length;i=i+2){
                lis +="<li>"+"<label>"+data[i]+"</label> <label>"+data[i+1]+"</label></li>";
            }
            lis+="</ul>";
            foodDive.html(lis);    
        });
    });
});
```

#### css

```
.foodsSection{
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    border: black solid 2px;
}
.foodsSection label{
    width: 100px;
    color: blue;
}
.foodsSection ul{
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    padding: 0;
}
.foodsSection ul li{
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    list-style: none;
}
.foodsSection ul li:hover{
    background-color: #ccccff;
}
```

Comment: and how to put the database in `fiddle` ?

Comment: I don't know if theres any connection, but you have doubble dots in  $("..RestauranstSection li").click(function ()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are appending another `ul` element to the current `ul`. You can either replace the `ul` or only append `li` elements.

```
foodDive.replaceWith(lis);
```

Comment: yes you right, thank you i will accept your answer after 10 mins

Answer (score 4):

You are setting the HTML of the `foodsSection ul` with another `ul`. e.g.

You are selecting `$(".foodsSection ul")` which is the `ul` element. Then setting the HTML within it with another `ul`.

```
<div class="foodsSection">
    <label>
        Foods:
    </label>
    <ul>
        <ul>
         .
         .
         .
         </ul>
     </ul>
 </div>
```

This is going to cause twice the amount of padding and also is **incorrect HTML markup**. It may look wrong in one browser (due to the double padding) but is going to look worse it others due to the broken HTML.

What you can do is replace your `.html(lis)` line of code with `.replaceWith(lis)` You can read about this method here [.replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/)

Answer (score 1):

Its because you are adding the code to the ul element, and it includes a nexted ul. Firefox developer toolbar has a "view generated source" button that is useful for this.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("..RestauranstSection li").click(function (){
        var divYourOrder = $(".YourOrder");
        var li = $(".OMRestaurants li");
        var restaurantID = 8;
        var foodDive = $(".foodsSection ul");
        foodDive.html("");
        var lis = '';
        $.getJSON("http://localhost/TheEatTel/Food/getFoodForRestaurant/"+restaurantID+"/TRUE",function(data){
            for(var i=0;i<data.length;i=i+2){
                lis +="<li>"+"<label>"+data[i]+"</label> <label>"+data[i+1]+"</label></li>";
            }
            foodDive.html(lis);    
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are adding extra `<ul>` from your script. You already obtain destination for li with `var foodDive = $(".foodsSection ul");`.
So you don't need that 2nd `var lis = '<ul>';` and closing `lis+='</ul>'` too. Just just `var lis = '';` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding a second `ul` to your markup, and it is inheriting the css style for your `ul`(a margin left of 100px).

instead of

```
.foodsSection ul
```

try

```
.foodsSection > ul
```